# Python String cannot be converted to an integer

Tags: python, string, arduino, integer

I'm trying to read a sensor value from an Arduino Serial Port using the following Python script:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM5", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
def get_val():
    ser.write(b'g')
    return ser.readline().decode().rstrip()

while 1:
    data = get_val()
    print(data)
```

So far everything works very well, python prints the sensor values on the console as strings. But when I try to cast the String 'data' to an integer, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...] requestDataPoint.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(int(data))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: what do you get if you just print without the int

Comment: I get a set of sensor values, like: 

899
895
847
847
899
871
843
871
867
843
895
871
899
843
847
867
895
843
895
851
851
867
867
871
843
895
847
867
843
867
871
871

Comment: like that whole thing? or one at a time?

Comment: One for every iteration of the while loop.

Comment: What confuses me is that the string after "invalid literal" is empty : ''

Comment: Sometimes the output of the serial port can be empty. You could use the try/catch statement to convert your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here I can suggest some troubleshooting here,

First, check the length of the string of first output and if it matches the integer value, then stop the iteration and check for just 1 value and check by `num.isdigit()` and if it does not match with the length then there is a space between numbers, you then have to remove the space in between the numbers.